# Automatically sending all wallet balance after removing charges using ethers js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, ethers.js

I want my code to be able to send all balance of the wallet after calculating and removing transaction charges. I have tried manipulation the gasPrice against the gasLimit but not working as expected, I want a **zero balance** after the sendTransation. What am I missing in my code below

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

const {ether, ethers, providers} = require("ethers");
const { toBn } = require("evm-bn");
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/9aa3d95b3bc440fa88ea12eaa4456161");
const addressReceiver = "0xxxxxxxx";

const privateKeys = [
   '42c5f2edd7add2a546xxxxxx73eefd9332b1be4fd3a35',
   'f253426203a43a3addxxxxxxxxxxx4fea46164a3875c6a25f2',
   '8bedd1004cfc171bc30a1a324e6xxxxxxxxxxxx6a86ba00dfe0cf09d332ad9',
   '5fcec6f54224b70cexxxxxxxxxxxx8cb46ec7ace9c86936ae'
]

const bot = async () => {

  provider.on("block", async () => {
    //console.log("Listening new block, waiting..)");
    for (let i = 0; i < privateKeys.length; i++) {
      const _target = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeys[i]);
    
      const target = _target.connect(provider);
      const userAdress = target.address;
      const balance = await provider.getBalance(userAdress);
      //console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance));
      const txBuffer = ethers.utils.parseEther(".0005");
      
      if (balance.sub(txBuffer) >= 0) {
        console.log("NEW ACCOUNT WITH ETH");
        const amount = balance.sub(txBuffer);

        const txFee = ethers.utils.parseUnits('20', 'gwei') * 21000;

        const vTXFEE = ethers.utils.formatEther(txFee);
        const SENDV =  ethers.utils.formatEther(amount);

        const FINALSEND = SENDV-vTXFEE;
  
        const BN =  toBn(FINALSEND.toString());
       
        try {
          await target.sendTransaction({
            to: addressReceiver,
            value: BN
          });
          console.log("success");
          //console.log(`Success! transfered --> ${ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)}`);
        }
        catch (e) {
          console.log("Error");
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
bot();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  
  res.send("<h1>Ethereum Bot Started!</h1>")

})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, 
    () => console.log("Server is running..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the gas price then multiply it with 21000

```
const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice()
const estimateTxFee = gasPrice.mul(21000)
const BN = balance.sub(estimateTxFee)
```

Gas in ethereum is a different unit from the transaction fee which is in wei/gwei. You get the transaction fee by multiplying the gas and the gas price which varies from time to time.

---

Although I'm not certain whether 21000 is a fixed gas amount for a normal send transaction. So you could do something like this also:

```
const estimateGas = await providers.estimateGas({
  to: addressReceiver,
  value: balance
})
const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice()
const estimateTxFee = gasPrice.mul(estimateGas)
const BN = balance.sub(estimateTxFee)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using ethers.js version 6.6.2

const gasPrice = (await provider.getFeeData()).gasPrice;
console.log(gasPrice)

this works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let balance = await provider.getBalance(wallet.address);
 balance = balance.sub(ethers.utils.parseEther(feeAmount));
```